# What's wrong with my proof that $f(x) = x^2, x^4, \ldots$ are bijective?

Tags: functions, proof-verification

> Let $n$ be an odd positive integer. Prove $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow
> > \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = x^n$ is bijective.

My attempt:

First we prove injectivity. Suppose we have $f(x) = f(y)$ so that $x^n = y^n$. Raising to the $(1/n)^{\text{th}}$ power, we get $x = y$, from which injectivity follows.

Now we prove surjectivity. We want to find $x$ so that $f(x) = y$. Taking $x = y^{1/n}$ works.

---

My question:

1) Is this proof correct for odd $n$?

2) Why does it fail for $n$ even?

Comment: $x^n=y^n$ is equivalent to $(x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+...+y^{n-1})=0$. If $n$ is odd, then $x$ and $y$ must have the same sign. Therefore, the factor $x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+...+y^{n-1}$ is $0$ only when $x=y=0$. Otherwise, it isn't, which forces $x-y=0$. In both cases $x=y$. This proves injectivity.

Answer (score 3):

Your proof is not correct because it assumes that there is a function $x\mapsto\sqrt[n]x$ which is an inverse of $x\mapsto x^n$. But you are supposed to *prove* that that inverse *exists*!

Comment: So it's wrong for odd $n$ as well?

Comment: Yes, it is wrong.

Comment: Not necessarily. The OP might already know that $x^{1/n}$ exists for all $x$, $n$ odd and then it is ok.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta I agree, but I find it unlikely. Let us see what the OP has to say about this.

Comment: Indeed, probably there wasn't given a formal proof.

Comment: No, this is my proof. I wasn't given anything. So it's wrong. Let me try again

Comment: @wutv1922 Hints: in order to prove that it is injective, prove that it is strictly increasing. In order to prove that it is surjective, use the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: The issue I'm having is that the derivative is not strictly greater than $0$. I get $nx^{n - 1} \geq 0$ which is true because $x^{n - 1}$ is an even power of $x$. Now I need to show $nx^{n - 1} \geq 0$ to get the "strict" part

Comment: I would prove that it is strictly increasing *without* derivatives. But note that a function $f$ such that $f'$ is never negative and which is such that the zeros of $f'$ are isolated points is still strictly increasing.

Comment: Ok. I proved injectivity using difference of $n^{\text{th}}$ power. For surjectivity is this right: Let $y \in \mathbb{R}$  be a point. We want to find $x$ such that $f(x) = y$. Choose a suitably small $\epsilon > 0$ such that $y - \epsilon < y < y + \epsilon$. Since $f$ is continuous and strictly increasing, we have $f(y-\epsilon) < f(y + \epsilon)$. Hence, by IVT, there exists $z$ such that $f(z) = y$ where $z$ is between $y-\epsilon$ and $y+\epsilon$

Comment: No. If that was correct, then every strictly increasing function would be surjective. Take $y\in\mathbb R$. Take $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $-N^n(=(-N)^n)<y<N^n$. Then, by the intermediate value theorem, there is a real number $x$ such that $x^n=y$.

Answer (score 1):

It is incorrect.

Your proof only holds for odd $n$!

Indeed, we have $f(1)=f(-1)$ for $n$ even.

---

Your proof for $n$ is even breaks down because we have

$$(x^n)^{1/n} = |x|$$

---

Here are hints how you can formally show that $x \mapsto x^n$ is bijective for $n$ odd (without assuming $n$-th roots exist!)

**Injective**: Because the function is strictly increasing (prove this using derivatives).

**Surjective**: By continuity and the mean value theorem.

Comment: Yes I know we have $f(1) = f(-1)$. I mean is my proof correct for odd $n$, and where does the proof break down for even $n$

Comment: I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For $n$ even, $f(-1)=f(1)$ and for $n$ odd, $f(-1)=-f(1)$. So for $n$ even, the function cannot be one-to-one. For $n$ odd, it is.

Answer (score 1):

The map $x\mapsto x^{1/n}$ only exists when $n$ is odd. As is, your proof is wrong because you have not shown the map exists. You have not even shown it exists for odd $n$, and you're lucky it does.

As an alternative, try showing $x\mapsto x^n$ is monotonously increasing and continuous to show it is a bijection (when $n$ is odd). It should be obvious why this does not work when $n$ is even.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you mean "fails for $n$ even". Your proof is fine for $n$ odd.

The problem depends on your perspective, I will express it in two ways:

1. "There is no $n^{\text{th}}$ root is $n$ is even."
2. "The standard $\sqrt[n]{x}$ is not an inverse function."

   I'll focus on the case $n=2$, but the argument is completely general.

Write $f(x) = x^{2}$ and $g(x) = \sqrt{x}$. The question is, what is $fg$ and what is $gf$. To answer this, we need to know what $g$ really means. Suppose you 'define'
$$g(x^{2}) = x\quad \text{for every $x$}$$
The important thing to realise is that this is **not a function**! Why? Because the function has to be well defined by its input - if we take the input to be $1$, then we have simultaneously:
$$g(1^{2}) = 1$$
$$g((-1)^{2}) = -1$$
which would be a contradiction. The *usual* definition of square rooting says that we take the **positive** square root, so that unambiguously, $g(1)=1$.

The problem *now* is that even though $f(g(x))$ equals $x$ for every $x \ge 0$, we do **not** always have $g(f(x)) = x$: for example, $g(f(-1)) = g(1) = 1$.

So, saying "taking $n^{\text{th}}$ roots" does not make sense for even $n$.